как настроить бота в тг, чтобы он удалял сообщения по слову «заработок»?
я хочу создать бота, чтобы он удалял сообщения в публичном чате. Удалять сообщения он должен по слову «заработок» «работа» и тд.
такие сообщения сейчас отправляют везде в чатах боты, которые заходят, а потом выходят из чата.
надо решить эту проблему, но я не знаю как. я пытался задать команду, чтобы он удалял соо, связанные со словом «заработок».
помогите, пожалуйста.

Судя по конструкции вопроса вам на фриланс биржу
